# How to create a form in NextJS using App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

There's a pretty clear official approach for [creating forms using Pages Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/building-forms) , but this is not the case in `App Router`.

My first guess would be using a [POST Router handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers) but documentation states:

> **Note**: Previously, API Routes could have been used for use cases like
> handling form submissions. Route Handlers are likely not the solution
> for these uses cases. We will be recommending the use of mutations for
> this when ready.

However, this mutations (aka [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions)) are an alpha feature. So, **should I ignore the recommendation and stay with `Router Handler` instead? Any other pattern I might be missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this warning was changed, and it now says that it's fine to use Route Handlers for such cases:

> **Good to know:** Like API Routes, Route Handlers can be used for cases like handling form submissions. A new abstraction for [handling forms and mutations](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions) that integrates deeply with React is being worked on.

Route Handlers (`app/api`) are basically the equivalent of API Routes (which live inside the `pages/api` directory). And you don't even need to migrate right away or anything like that, API routes still work even if you use App router for the rest of your app. So you can still follow [this old guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/building-forms) and keep the `pages/api/form.js` file, or if you like, rework it to `app/api/route.js`.

With both Route Handlers and API routes, you can create interactive forms, with JavaScript-based validation etc, and native HTML forms that work even with JS disabled.

Comment: Thank you @Danila, it seems they changed the warning indeed, unfortunately I already went for server actions (which actually work pretty good), but as for now this seems the "official" recommended method :)